# Adding attachment to email php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email, attachment

Hi guys I have got a newsletter script which will send whatever the administrator has put in the text area to all the emails in the database, now I would like that user also be able to upload a .pdf file to that email, Any help much appreciated! here is the code of actually sending out the email:

Plain is the textarea with the message
Subject is the subject
Will need to add a upload input on the form which validates to this script

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
$subject = stripslashes($_POST["subject"]);
$plain = stripslashes($_POST["plain"]);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM member");
$emails = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
$emails[] = $row[0];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$from = "noreply@wgtfgb.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
$to = implode(", ", $emails);

mail($to, $_POST['subject'], $_POST["plain"], $headers);
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
<form id='register' action='updateprofile.php' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
<div id="form_container">

<h1>Newsletter Sent</h1>
    <form id="form_362567" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
                <div class="form_description">
        <h2>&nbsp;Newsletter Sent</h2>
        <p></p>
    </div>                      
        <ul >

                <li class="section_break">

        <p></p>
    </li>       <li id="li_2" >
    <label class="description" for="email">
    <?php
echo "Newsletter successfully sent, you will be redirected back to the member area in     5     seconds.";
?>
</form>
        <div id="footer">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=index.php">
    </div>
</div>
<img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
</body>
```

Comment: save your self pain, stop using the very basic(underpowered and slow) mail() function

Comment: Seems alright to me? what is so bad about it..? Is this possible or not

Comment: possible, but the function has very limited 'power' no one uses it for anything but sending very basic email

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like SwiftMailer (http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html)... much easier to add attachements.

Comment: is this not possible with a normal function in php?

Answer (score 0):

PEAR_mail is a simple and well supported replacement for the PHP built in mail function. It has support for mime encoding and attachments and excellent documentation for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: is this not possible with just mail ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    <?php
            $fp = fopen('myfile.pdf','rb'); 
            $dt = fread($fp,filesize('myfile.pdf'));

            $attachments[] = Array(
               'data' => $dt,
               'name' => $name,
               'type' => 'application/pdf'
            ); 

              //Generate a boundary string

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

            $emailcontent="<style type='text/css'>
                        body {
                            font-family: arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
                            font-size: 12px;
                        }
                        </style>";


            $subject = 'Subject';

            $my_message = 'My message';

            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
                       "From: {$from}\n" .
                        "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
                       " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


                //Add a multipart boundary above the plain message


            $final_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
                      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
                      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
                      $my_message . "\n\n";


                //Add sttachments

            foreach($attachments as $attachment){
               $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($attachment['data']));
               $name = $attachment['name'];
               $type = $attachment['type'];

               $final_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
                          "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
                          " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .              
                          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
                          $data;
            }

            $final_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

        $emailto = 'myeamil@test.com';

        mail($emailto, $subject, $final_message, $headers);


?>
```

I used this code a long time ago to attach attachments. I am not sure if it is still working.